# Qual a diferença técnica entre os certificados SSL e EV SSL?

Tags: ssl, certificado-digital

Estou na fase de implementação da API da Cielo no meu site. No site de integração há dois tipos de certificados[nesse link](http://developercielo.github.io/Webservice-3.0/#certificado-extended-validation), O EV SSL, e o SSL.

Sinceramente eu estou mexendo com certificado pela primeira vez, conheço o SSL mas não entendi a diferença técnica entre os dois, apenas a diferença entre o preço que é astronômica.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A diferença entre os dois é uma questão burocrática.

Ambos garantem praticamente o mesmo nível de segurança contra ataques eletrônicos. O que o EV dá a mais é uma garantia de que a entidade que emite o certificado (i.e.: GoDaddy, Digicert etc.) realmente investigou a empresa que comprou o certificado para garantir que se trata de uma entidade legítima e idônea.

Em outras palavras, o EV SSL é um SSL combinado com um "certificado de bons antecedentes".

Os critérios de investigação são definidos pela [CA/Browser Forum](https://cabforum.org/), um consórcio de autoridades de certificação. Atualmente, para conseguir um EV SLL, você precisa provar o seguinte:

- Que o seu domínio é posse de uma pessoa física ou jurídica, com endereço físico (da pessoa, não da placa do servidor) conhecido. Acredito que isso requer ao menos uma entrevista, pois a Wiki relacionada diz que eles procuram estabelecer sua presença "física e operacional";
- Garantir que a pessoa física ou jurídica acima é a única dona e controladora do domínio que receberá o certificado;
- Garantir a identidade de todas as pessoas que possuem autorização do dono do domínio para representá-lo.

Como pode ver, se trata de um nível de avaliação bastante alto e custoso. Mas isso dá uma garantia aos usuários de que o dono do site é uma pessoa justa e que todos sabem onde mora, e não o hackovisky num porão da Sibéria tentando roubar o número do seu cartão de crédito.

E finalmente... Para demonstrar a segurança mais elevada de sites com EV SSL, os browsers atuais pintam algumas partes da barra de endereço de verde - e para acessibilidade para daltônicos, também costumam exibir um cadeado e a palavra "seguro".

Comment: *Hackovisky* num porão da Sibéria. kkkkkkkk

Comment: Agora entendi a diferença ! Resposta perfeita, obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

[Fonte](https://br.godaddy.com/web-security/ssl-certificate/ev-ssl-certificate)

> A Validação Estendida (EV) é a mais alta classe de Certificado SSL disponível. Apesar de ela usar a mesma criptografia poderosa que os outros SSLs, para tê-la é preciso uma verificação total dos negócios do requerente. O que você recebe é uma barra de endereços verde de alta visibilidade que faz com que os visitantes se sintam seguros instantaneamente. Se você aceita pagamentos online, o EV é a sua melhor aposta.

**A diferença**

> O primeiro exemplo é um certificado SSL normal, o que significa que é um certificado válido emitido por uma Autoridade de Certificação confiável, mas não houve validação estendida do proprietário do domínio / site. Isso pode significar que o certificado afirma ser da Foo Inc., mas a CA não verificou se a pessoa / entidade que solicitou o certificado era na verdade a Foo Inc. quando emitiram o certificado.
>
> O segundo exemplo é o de um Certificado SSL de Extended Validation. Este tipo de certificado faz validação estendida em que a CA verifica o endereço físico e outros detalhes da Foo Inc. antes de emitir o certificado. No final, isso serve para dar mais segurança ao usuário final que o proprietário do site / domínio é de fato a empresa Foo Inc.

[Fonte](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65631/what-is-the-difference-between-ev-ssl-certificates-and-normal-ssl-certificates)

Além disso a barra ficará com aquele verde que gera uma sensação de "super seguro"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eis uma [resposta](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15865/what-are-the-advantages-of-ev-certificate) bem detalhada:

Comment: Mano... O IE tenta, tenta e tenta mas não consegue deixar de ser o pior navegador em tudo. Além de posicionar a informação de segurança (fora a cor) onde o usuário não vai ler, ainda coloca de forma que não se destaca do resto dos símbolos (recarregar, parar etc). </desabafo>

Comment: Resposta 10/10 também, obrigado !

Comment: @Renan O IE é um lixo em tudo... A merd* é que é padrão no windows, então tem lá sua relevância...